# Interval of Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

If the sequence of functions $g_n$ converges to $g$ uniformly on the interval $[1/n, 1]$, where $n$ is a natural number, must it converge uniformly to $g$ on the interval $[0,1]$?

I came across this question in a textbook and was not really sure how to proceed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily.  For example, you could define the sequence $(g_n(x))$ by $$g_n(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0,&\text{if } x=0,\\
1,&\text{if } 0<x<\frac 1n,\\
0, &\text{if } x\ge \frac 1n.\end{array}\right.$$
Then $g_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $g(x)=0$ on every interval $[\frac 1N, 1]$, but not on $[0,1]$.